# Cross compile C++ to ARM on Darwin

Tags: c++, ios, arm, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to cross compile some trivial C++ code to Mach-O ARM, for linking in an iOS app, yet cannot find `memory.h` in my includes. Why would `unique_ptr` not be present in `#include <memory>` ?

For reference, the code in question is below:

**command**

```
aarch64-apple-ios-clang++ -v main.cpp
```

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

typedef std::unique_ptr<int> Ptr;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    std::cout << "hey" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**result**

```
main.cpp:5:14: error: no template named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'
typedef std::unique_ptr<int> Ptr;
        ~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

verbose info:

```
clang version 7.1.0 (tags/RELEASE_710/final)
Target: aarch64-apple-ios
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /nix/store/j1gnbfpi25dw68d6idlxrxibycvirnbw-clang-7.1.0/bin
```

Include directories used:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /nix/store/1b66yzqcw1lnfnp8fak3bxyd7v0ksmsz-libSystem-prebuilt/include
 /nix/store/qgv5pfrjsi5vyffk0kwqibg403z3cdiw-Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
 /nix/store/8bikjdrf8gqzf3k94wgj15nfffvbqx8q-libc++-7.1.0/include/c++/v1
 /nix/store/qgv5pfrjsi5vyffk0kwqibg403z3cdiw-Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /nix/store/j1gnbfpi25dw68d6idlxrxibycvirnbw-clang-7.1.0/lib/clang/7.1.0/include
End of search list.
```